# Changing specific value in a dictionary while finding it by it's key

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, generics

I have a dictionary called users, i want to modify/change a specific value withing dictionary while doing that i try to find that value by searching through keys..
i dont know how to change that value into something else :)
I'm not sure if its even possible but wonder if its possible what is the syntax.. ty in advance. o/

txtRecoveryCustomerId.Text is a param that is written by user to start recovery process.
All is simulation im just trying to learn :)

```
Dictionary<string, string> users = new Dictionary<string, string>();
users.Add("12345", "666");
 foreach (var item in users)
            {
                if (item.Key.Contains(txtRecoveryCustomerId.Text))
                {
                   
                    //item.Replace(Convert.ToChar(users.Values), Convert.ToChar(txtPasswordChange.Text));
                }
            }
```

Comment: In a dictionary you do not need to loop, you simply look for the key in the dictionary `users["txtRecoveryCustomerId.Text"]` and if anything exists at that key, the return value is the value. Otherwise, an exception is thrown. To avoid the exception check first using `ContainsKey` or one of the other methods.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to perform two operations, neither of which requires a loop.

1. Ensure the user exists (aka: the dictionary contains the key)
2. Set the value stored by that key

You can use the following code to accomplish this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> users = new Dictionary<string, string>();
users.Add("12345", "666");

// reset password if the user exists
if (users.ContainsKey(txtRecoveryCustomerId.Text))
    users[txtRecoveryCustomerId.Text] = txtPasswordChange.Text;
```

Comment: yea worked fine ty so much :)) reallly appreciate :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   foreach (var item in users)
   if (item.Key.Contains(txtRecoveryCustomerId.Text))
  {
    users[item.Key] = txtPasswordChange.Text;
   break;
  }
```

Comment: this also worked fine :)) ty so much !